# How to send empty response for rest call in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have rest service for delete operation which actually return nothing. How to return nothing()void response as response in Apache camel rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value = URI_REMOVE_ACTIVITY_DELETE, method = DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        super.delete(id, principal);
    } 
    Class<Void> RESULT_URI_REMOVE_ACTIVITY_DELETE = void.class;
```

Comment: Are you asking for route definitions to replace the service in your example? Shouldn't DELETE return a 200/204, to stick with standards? By returning `Nothing`, did you mean a 204 empty response?

Comment: I get the request as a JSON like {delete:123}, which is returned in the response as part of the 200 success message. 
It possible because of my json binding which is applied to response message body automatically.
I want to send the 200 response only but with message body as empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a primitive implementation that you can further improve on.

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {

        restConfiguration().component("jetty").host("localhost").port("8080");

        rest().produces("application/json").delete("/something/{id}").to("direct:delete");
        from("direct:delete")
                .log("Delete ${in.header.id}")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String id = exchange.getIn().getHeader("id",String.class);
                    //doDelete(id);
                })
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,constant(200));


    }
}
```

`exchange.getIn().getHeader("id",String.class)` is the rough equivalent of `@PathVariable`. `@RequestMapping(value = URI_REMOVE_ACTIVITY_DELETE, method = DELETE)` should become `.delete(URI_REMOVE_ACTIVITY_DELETE)`

Response from the server below
[image]

Modified code with `bindingMode` set to JSON.

```
 public void configure() {

    restConfiguration().component("jetty").host("localhost").port("8080").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest().produces("text/plain").delete("/something").to("direct:delete");
    from("direct:delete")
            .process(exchange -> {
                Map<String, Object> requestObject = (Map<String, Object>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                //doDelete(requestObject.get("id"));
            })
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200));


}
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, actually we enabled bindingMode as JSON, so it returns the input Json value in my response. we need to have it blank..

Comment: Could you please post your RouteBuilder code to help us understand where you stand and to help further?

Comment: I see what you meant, after adding `bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)` to my test code. Unless you have complex marshalling/unmarshalling in place, you can override the response per REST endpoint with `produces` override.


Perhaps do `produces("text/plain")` (it will work with `application/json` just fine as well)  on this REST endpoint and at the end of the route just do `setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,constant(200))` exactly like the test code I have posted. It suppresses chaining the `request` object back to `response`. Additional code segment in answer.

Comment: yes thats right !!...We are using type in addition to the bindingMode..something like below  .type(MyObject.class)..so it tries to represent the object in response. we tried to use something like                                                .post().type(MyObject.class).outType(String.class)
                .responseMessage()
                    .code(200).message("message got deleted")